# How to get value from TypeScript Enum (Angular 6)

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I am saving the numeric value of an enum in my database and returning it to the UI in a different area. Now I want to extract the string value associated with that numeric value in the enum in a different angular component.

I have an enum like so:

```
export enum ReportedResourceStatusEnum {
    New = 1,
    Reviewed = 2,
    Escalated = 3,
    Resolved = 4
}
```

That value (the 1, 2, 3, 4) is stored as a string property (nvarchar) in the table. When I call the api, an object is returned like this:

```
{
   something: 'Something',
   status: '1'
}
```

When I display to the UI, the '1' is displayed. How do I inject the `Enum class` and extract the string associated with the value of 1. In this case, being the word `New`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax is: `ReportedResourceStatusEnum[1]`

Try this:

```
export enum ReportedResourceStatusEnum {
  New = 1,
  Reviewed = 2,
  Escalated = 3,
  Resolved = 4
}


export class AppComponent {
  data = {
    something: 'Something',
    status: '1'
  }

  constructor() {
    console.log(ReportedResourceStatusEnum[Number(this.data.status)]) //New
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.